# Testing Phoenix - If there's a foreign_key constraint, is there anyway to still use @valid_attrs?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

On most model tests you have access to `@valid_attrs`, which allows for simple creating of models, without having to constantly copy/type params.

If I have a user_id constraint (can't be a random number, because the ID is validated)

Is there anyway to still use `@valid_attrs`?

Right now, I'm creating a User in my `setup` block, then `Map.put(@valid_attrs, :user_id, user.id)` when I need to. Like this:

```
defmodule ModelTest do
  # Not really valid without user_id
  @valid_attrs %{name: "some content"}
  @invalid_attrs %{}

  setup do
    {:ok, user} = User.registration_changeset(User{}, %{username: "tester_user", email: "tester@test.com", password: "Password", password_confirmation: "Password"}) |> Repo.insert
    {:ok, %{user: user}}
  end

  test "some test", %{user: user} do
    {:ok, room} = Model.changeset(%Room{}, Map.put(@valid_attrs, :user_id, user.id)) |> Repo.insert
    ## test stuff
  end
end
```

It's a bit messy, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

I wouldn't call what you have messy, but I am guessing you want to use `valid_attrs` in multiple tests. You can just put the `user_id` in `valid_attrs` and return that in the `setup` block:

```
defmodule ModelTest do
  # Not really valid without user_id
  @valid_attrs %{name: "some content"}
  @invalid_attrs %{}

  setup do
    {:ok, user} = User.registration_changeset(User{}, %{username: "tester_user", email: "tester@test.com", password: "Password", password_confirmation: "Password"}) |> Repo.insert
    valid_attrs = Map.put(@valid_attrs, :user_id, user.id)
    {:ok, %{user: user, valid_attrs: valid_attrs}}
  end

  test "some test", %{user: user, valid_attrs: valid_attrs} do
    {:ok, room} = Model.changeset(%Room{}, valid_attrs) |> Repo.insert
    ## test stuff
  end
end
```

**Long Answer**

From [Programming Phoenix](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix) (which I highly recommend reading):

> In Phoenix, whenever it’s possible, we try to limit side
>   effects—functions that touch and possibly change the outside world—to
>   the controller. We’ll try to keep the functions in our models and
>   views pure, so that calling the same function with the same arguments
>   will always yield the same results.
>
> If you’re a diehard MVC person, you might have to reimagine the job of
>   the model layer. In Phoenix, you’ll want to separate the code that
>   calls another web server, or fetches code from a database, from the
>   code that processes that data. We process data in the model; we read
>   or write that data through the controller. Ecto allows us to organize
>   our code in this way. It separates the code with side effects, which
>   changes the world around us, from the code that’s only transforming
>   data.

Based on that, I would recommend not testing the foreign_key constraint in model tests, but in the controller tests (or a separate "model" test). In the model test, you can just validate the presence of the `user_id` (by including `user_id: 1` in your `@valid_attrs`).

Here's how the testing of a constraint (`unique_constraint` in this case, but the same could be applied to any constraints) was done in the sample application built in Programming Phoenix. In the [User Model](https://github.com/somlor/programming-phoenix/blob/master/rumbl/web/models/user.ex#L21), there is a `unique_constraint` on the `username`. The testing of the User Model was done in 2 separate test modules:

1. [UserTest](https://github.com/somlor/programming-phoenix/blob/master/rumbl/test/models/user_test.exs) where the `unique_constraint` was not tested and no call to the Repo was made and;
2. [UserRepoTest](https://github.com/somlor/programming-phoenix/blob/master/rumbl/test/models/user_repo_test.exs) where a call to the Repo was made to specifically test the constraint.